# In delphi 2010, Bitmap.Free works in Timer event, but not working in Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer

Friends
I have a problem. 
I am using DELPHI 2010 and making a project.. 
My function is as following...
It works properly in timer event, but the Bitmap.free doesn't work in Thread.
So it occures error and says "Project xxx.exe raised exception class EOutOfResources with message"

my code is like below.

```
{ScreenShot function}
procedure ScreenShot(Bild: TBitMap);
var
  c: TCanvas;
   r: TRect;
begin
  c := TCanvas.Create;
  c.Handle := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
    r := Rect(0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height);
    Bild.Width := Screen.Width;
    Bild.Height := Screen.Height;
    Bild.Canvas.CopyRect(r, c, r);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, c.Handle);
    c.Free;
  end;
end;

{Bitmap to Jpeg Function}
procedure Bmp2Jpeg(Bmp : TBitmap; JpgStream: TStream);
var
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    Jpg.Assign(Bmp);
    Jpg.CompressionQuality := 10;
    Jpg.Compress;
    Jpg.SaveToStream(JpgStream);

  finally
    Jpg.Free;
  end;

end;

{main function}
//this is in Timer or Thread Excute
procedure SendImage;
var
  Bmp:TBitmap;
  JpgStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  FidClient.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect(True, True);
  FidClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);

  try
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    jpgStream :=TMemoryStream.Create;
    jpgStream.Clear;
    Inc(Pic_Cnt);
    Bmp.PixelFormat :=pf16bit;
    Bmp.AlphaFormat :=afIgnored;
    ScreenShot(Bmp);

    Bmp2Jpeg(Bmp, TStream(jpgStream));


    jpgStream.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);

    if (SendStream(FidClient, TStream(jpgStream)) = False) **then**
    begin
      OutMsg :='sending error';
      FidClient.Disconnect;
    end
    else
    begin
      OutMsg:='sending successful';
    end;

  finally
    Bmp.Free; //this is main problem
    jpgStream.Free; //and this is also problem 

  end;

end;
```

I have debugged and compared two conditions those are in Timer and Thread.
In case of the Timer event, "**Bmp.Free**" and "**jpgStream.Free**" work well, but don't work in case of Thread....

Good Friends..
Pls give me advice.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure AV is raised only when calling `Bmp.Free` and `jpgStream.Free` from a different thread? Based on your code I would guess that AV is probably originating from your ScreenShot method which should not be called from a different thread since it is accessing UI components.

Comment: Also when preforming ScreenShot I would suggest you rather use code provided in this article http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips1999/qt/deskscreenshot.htm

Comment: The Delphi VCL GDI wrappers are not thread safe

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem at last !
The key is locking of TBITMAP

Modified code is like following....

```
procedure SendImage;
var
  Bmp:TBitmap;
  JpgStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  FidClient.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect(True, True);
  FidClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);

  try
    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    Bmp.Canvas.Lock; //lock bitmap
    jpgStream :=TMemoryStream.Create;
    jpgStream.Clear;
    Inc(Pic_Cnt);
    Bmp.PixelFormat :=pf16bit;
    Bmp.AlphaFormat :=afIgnored;
    ScreenShot(Bmp);

    Bmp2Jpeg(Bmp, TStream(jpgStream));


    jpgStream.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);

    if (SendStream(FidClient, TStream(jpgStream)) = False) **then**
    begin
      OutMsg :='sending error';
      FidClient.Disconnect;
    end
    else
    begin
      OutMsg:='sending successful';
    end;

  finally
    Bmp.Canvas.Unlock; //unlock Bitmap
    Bmp.Free; 
    jpgStream.Free; 

  end;

end;
```

So finally my problem is solved like this....
Thanks very much!!!